# Why is a Yocto recipe being skipped?

Tags: yocto

How do I find out the reason bitbake is skipping a recipe?

If run:

`>bitbake-layers show-appends`

I see the layer that I expected to be included is skipped:

`linux-96boards_4.4.bb (skipped):`

and the .bbappend to that recipe ignored. After looking into this, I've found the linux-96boards_4.4.bb recipe includes a number of .bbclass and .inc files and it is one of these files which is causing the skip. Is there a way to find out the reason for the skip and where in the code it happens?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe your machine is not in compatible ones, defined [here](https://github.com/96boards/meta-96boards/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-96boards_4.4.bb#L35)?

Comment: Thanks. I thought that too, if I add the machine to that line of code it still skips it, hence my wondering if there was a way to find out why. Anyhow it turns out I don’t need this layer anyway, so I’ve moved on now.

Comment: I would probably play with `bitbake -e linux-96boards` and `bitbake -v linux-96boards`, don't know if there are easiest ways.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.